# jQuery Mobile slider - make input be able to violate step

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile Slider element.  It's meant to be a percentage so it ranges from 0 to 100 for min/max.  Because it is used on a phone, I have the step set to 5 which I feel is easier to hit things like 25% or 50%.  But say someone wants 66%.  I want them to be able to type this value into the input box and have it update the slider to 66%.  Instead the slider falls back to 65%.

Can I allow a direct edit of the input box to alter the slider value?

[image]

Comment: you can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LSGAk/. change `step` value to `1` when textbox is edited. and once slider buttons is clicked, change `step` back to `10`.

Comment: Thanks, simple idea, and works well.  I decided to use the 'onfocus' event since it would get called less often.  But that does work.  Please post as a solution and I will accept.  I think you've answered some other of my questions as well, so thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I've been of help Paul :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change `step` value to whatever you want once a user enters a custom value. Later, change `step` to its original value.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LSGAk/)**

```
$(document).on('focus', '#slider-1', function () {
 $(this).attr('step', '1');
});

$(document).on('click', '.ui-slider-handle', function () {
 $('#slider-1').attr('step', '10');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest solution similar to Omar, but would leave `step` by default to lower value and use jQuery mobile `slidestart` and `slidestop` events. It works more reliable in my case.

```
$('#slider').on('slidestart', function(event) {
    $(this).attr('step', '5');
});

$('#slider').on('slidestop', function(event) {
    $(this).attr('step', '1');
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mpoiu/r3davybh/)